# Is there any way that i can perform bit manipulation with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, bit-manipulation

Write a function that swaps the highest bits in each nibble of the byte pointed to by the pointer b. (i.e. `0bAxxxBxxx` -> `0bBxxxAxxx`).

I have a predefined function with this prototype: `void swapBits(uint8_t* b);`

The solution that I came up with is not working -

```
void swapBits(uint8_t *b)              
{
    uint8_t bit1;
    uint8_t bit2;
    uint8_t x;
    bit1 = (*b >> 4) & 1;
    bit2 = (*b >> 8) & 1;
    x = bit1 ^ bit2;
    x = x << 4 | x << 8;
    *b = *b ^ x;    
}
```

Comment: `*b >> 8` is 0 for all `b`  What that intended?

Comment: You should use a debugger and you will see where your logic fails. Btw. `x = 1 ^ 1 -> 0`

Answer (score 2):

there are couple problems:

1. to get 4th bit from the right you need to shift 3 times (not four)
2. xor is probably not what you need to use

here is fixed version:

```
void swapBits(uint8_t* b)              
{
     uint8_t bit1;
     uint8_t bit2;
     bit1 = ((*b >> 3) & 1) << 7; // get bit from one position and put it into another
     bit2 = ((*b >> 7) & 1) << 3;
     *b = (*b & 0x77) | bit1 | bit2; // clear already extracted bits and reset with new values
}
```

Comment: xor can be used to swap 2 bits: if and only if they differ, xoring the value with `0x88` does swap the values. You approach is simpler and can be used to swap more than 1 bit at a time.

Comment: I'm trying to call your code in this way -

int main()
{
    uint8_t byte[8] = {0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0};
    swapBits(byte);
    printf("byte after: %01x%01x%01x%01x%01x%01x%01x%01x\n", byte[0], byte[1], byte[2], byte[3], byte[4], byte[5], byte[6], byte[7]);
}

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @codemaverick it looks like you're trying to swap bytes, not bits `uint8_t byte[8]` is array of 8 bytes, this function swap 4th and 8th bit in first byte, as soon as it is 0x1 = 00000001, it swaps 0 with 0

Answer (score 2):

You are extracting the low bit in the high nibble and shift out the whole `uint8_t` for `bit2`. You need to extract the high bit in both.

Example:

```c
void swapBits(uint8_t* b)              
{
     // shift down the high nibble and get its MSb
     uint8_t bit1 = (*b >> 4) & 0b1000;

     // get the MSb in the low nibble and shift it up
     uint8_t bit2 = (*b & 0b1000) << 4;

     // remove whatever values the MSbs had and replace them with the new values
     *b = (*b & 0b01110111) | bit2 | bit1;
}
```

`0b` for binary literals is a gcc extension (but will become standard in C23). If you can't use it, use a plain `8` instead of `0b1000` and `0x77` instead of `0b01110111`. I'm using the extension because it makes it easier to see the patterns.

---

A more generic version where you can supply the mask for the the bits to swap between the nibbles could look like this:

```c
uint8_t swapBits(uint8_t b, uint8_t m) {
     return (b & ~(m << 4 | m)) // remove the bits in the mask
          | ((b >> 4) & m)      // high nibble bits -> low nibble
          | ((b & m) << 4);     // low nibble bits -> high nibble
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W633eaWbo)

Comment: Is this solution endiansafe?

Comment: @klutt Yes, it will swap the MSb in the nibbles regardless of what endianess the machine has.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because you shift the byte values by `4` and `8` instead of `3` and `7`.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
void swapBits(uint8_t *b) {
    uint8_t bit1 = (*b >> 3) & 1;
    uint8_t bit2 = (*b >> 7) & 1;
    uint8_t x = bit1 ^ bit2;
    *b ^= (x << 3) | (x << 7);
}
```

Here is a simplified version:

```
void swapBits(uint8_t *b) {
    uint8_t x = (*b ^ (*b >> 4)) & 0x08;
    *b ^= x * 0x11;
}
```

Here is an alternative approach that can be used for more multiple bits:

```
void swapBits(uint8_t *b) {
     uint8_t bit7 = (*b & 0x08) << 4;
     uint8_t bit3 = (*b & 0x80) >> 4;
     *b = (*b & 0x77) | bit7 | bit3;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, the alternative approach is what I would have written too, without pondering on the problem too much. It performs well, although the XOR version seems to shave off a few more instructions even further.